# Why store event.target in a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In examples of React event handler methods like the following, I've been seeing `event.target` stored in a variable. In this example, it seems like it would be simpler to just set the variable `value` to `event.target.checked`. Is there any advantage to storing `event.target` in the `target` variable rather than just having `const value = event.target.checked`?

```
handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.checked;

    this.setState({
      something: value
    });
  }
```

Comment: i mean, what do you even need `value` for?

Comment: @KevinB To use in the object in `setState`, it looks like

Comment: Right, but you can use the same logic to eliminate that variable too.

Comment: It may simply be an odd attempt by the tutorial to make things "simpler" for newbies by not accessing nested properties all at once, though it's kind of confusing for anyone experienced. In a more complicated situation, extracting properties into variables first can make code more readable, but that's not the case here I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store event.target in a variable. In fact you don't even need to pass the event object if you don't need it. In your example the checked value would suffice. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" value={this.state.something} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.checked)}/>
```

And then

```
handleChange(isChecked) {
  this.setState({
    something: isChecked
  });
}
```